# Existential type that can be expressed with wildcard cause different behavior

Tags: scala, generics, type-safety, existential-type

Consider the following example:

```
sealed trait Test

case object A extends Test

sealed trait Type {
  type Tst <: Test
}

type Aux[T <: Test] = Type { type Tst = T }

case object Type1 extends Type {
  type Tst = A.type
}

case class Model[T <: Type](t: T)

val a: Model[Aux[A.type]] = null

val b: Model[_ <: Aux[_ <: Test]] = a //Compiles fine

val c: Model[T forSome { type T <: Aux[_ <: Test]}] = a  //Compile error type mismatch
```

[Scastie Demo](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/YJQnxDIOSIuwqSobKLqxAg)

I thought that types of `val b` and `val c` are the same. Why doesn't the later case compile?

Comment: [The docs](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#existential-types) talk about this. Scroll down to the section "Placeholder Syntax for Existential Types"

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to extract the existential type definition outside of the parameter list as follows

```
val c: Model[T] forSome { type T <: Aux[_ <: Test]} = a

val d: Model[T] forSome { type T <: Aux[T] forSome { type T <: Test}} = a
```

The behavior is highly non-obvious though and I found the solution by some wierd experiments.